# Install realtime kernel for Linux kernel 4.14 on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I have an AWS EC2 instance with CentOS and would like to make it run the realtime kernel. The system details are:

```
Current kernel: 4.14.62-70.117.amzn2.x86_64
Result of running cat /etc/*release:
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
Amazon Linux 2'
```

Firstly, is realtime still relevant in kernel versions beyond 3.x? If so, can anyone point me in the direction of a walk-through to update to a realtime kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need realtime kernel for virtual machine? It make no sense to use RT kernel, because you do not have control on hardware and timing will be always bad.